# How can I handle different types using generic type in swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write a class which allows me to easily interpolate between two values.

```
class Interpolation
{
    class func interpolate<T>(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> T
    {
        // Safety
        assert(progress >= 0 && progress <= 1, "Invalid progress value: \(progress)")

        if let a = from as? CGFloat, let b = to as? CGFloat
        {
        }
        if let a = from as? CGPoint, let b = to as? CGPoint
        {

        }
        if let from = from as? CGRect, let to = to as? CGRect
        {
            var returnRect = CGRect()
            returnRect.origin.x     = from.origin.x + (to.origin.x-from.origin.x) * progress
            returnRect.origin.y     = from.origin.y + (to.origin.y-from.origin.y) * progress
            returnRect.size.width   = from.size.width + (to.size.width-from.size.width) * progress
            returnRect.size.height  = from.size.height + (to.size.height-from.size.height) * progress
            return returnRect // Cannot convert return expression of type 'CGRect' to return type 'T'
        }

        return from
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me an error at `return returnRect`: Cannot convert return expression of type 'CGRect' to return type 'T'. Maybe I'm not understanding how generics are used...I just want to have one function that will handle interpolating between various types, rather than having a bunch of functions like `func interpolate(from: Int, to: Int)`, `func interpolate(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint)`, etc.

Comment: (1) It's better implemented using a protocol. (2) Just use the [dclelland/Lerp](https://github.com/dclelland/Lerp) instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `T` is a generic placeholder – meaning that you cannot know what the actual concrete type of `T` is from within the function. Therefore although you are able to conditionally cast `from` and `to` to a `CGRect` (thus establishing that `T == CGRect`), Swift is unable to infer this information and therefore prohibits attempting to return a `CGRect` when it expects a return of `T`.

The crude solution therefore is to force cast the return result back to `T` in order to bridge this gap in information with the type-system:

```
if let from = from as? CGRect, let to = to as? CGRect {

    // ...

    return returnRect as! T
}
```

However, this kind of type-casting is really a sign that you're fighting the type-system and not taking advantage of the static typing that generics offer, and therefore is not recommended.

The better solution, as [@Wongzigii has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38653299/2976878), is to use a protocol. For example, if you define an `Interpolate` protocol as he shows in his answer – you can then use this protocol in order to constrain your generic placeholder `T` in your `interpolate` function:

```
class Interpolation {
    class func interpolate<T:Interpolate>(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> T {

        // Safety
        assert(progress >= 0 && progress <= 1, "Invalid progress value: \(progress)")

        return T.interpolate(from: from, to: to, progress: progress)
    }
}
```

This solves many of your problems – it does away with the runtime type-casting and instead uses the protocol constraint in order to call the specialised `interpolate` function. The protocol constraint also prevents you from passing any types that don't conform to `Interpolate` at compile-time, and therefore also solves the problem of what to do when your type-casting fails.

Although that being said, I actually quite like the solution that [@JoshCaswell suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687308/2976878) to your other question – overloading operators in order to achieve this functionality. As with the previous solution, the key is to define a protocol that encapsulates the functionality you're defining on each type, and then constrain your generic function to this protocol.

A simple implementation may look like this:

```
protocol Interpolatable {
    func +(lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs:Self, rhs:CGFloat) -> Self
}

func +(lhs:CGRect, rhs:CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: lhs.origin.x+rhs.origin.x,
                  y: lhs.origin.y+rhs.origin.y,
                  width: lhs.size.width+rhs.size.width,
                  height: lhs.size.height+rhs.size.height)
}

func -(lhs:CGRect, rhs:CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: lhs.origin.x-rhs.origin.x,
                  y: lhs.origin.y-rhs.origin.y,
                  width: lhs.size.width-rhs.size.width,
                  height: lhs.size.height-rhs.size.height)
}

func *(lhs:CGRect, rhs:CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: lhs.origin.x*rhs,
                  y: lhs.origin.y*rhs,
                  width: lhs.size.width*rhs,
                  height: lhs.size.height*rhs)
}

extension CGRect : Interpolatable {}
extension CGFloat : Interpolatable {}

class Interpolation {
    class func interpolate<T:Interpolatable>(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> T {
        assert(progress >= 0 && progress <= 1, "Invalid progress value: \(progress)")
        return from + (to - from) * progress
    }
}
```

Comment: I had misunderstood @Wongzigii's answer. I thought he meant to make a protocol that the CGPoint, CGRect, etc classes would implement, which wouldn't be much different from just extending those classes with an interpolate function of their own. This is what I'm looking for. One question though - what should I do if the operator overloading conflicts with another library that offers the same operator overloading for two points or two rects? Just use an infix operator?

Comment: @GoldenJoe Depends on how the operator overloads are implemented by that other library. If it's the same implementation as the above, then you can simply ditch your own overloads and rely on the library's overloads instead (but still use the protocol to constrain the generic function). If they have a different implementation (I cannot immediately think of a logical implementation of `CGRect + CGRect` that doesn't just add the components) – then you could instead define your own functions on `CGRect` that deal with adding, subtracting etc.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/88157c973cb6db9ba2f701eb5c2495a0) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you use `Protocol` to scale your *generic*  type.

```
protocol Interpolate {
    associatedtype T
    static func interpolate(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> T
}
```

Then let `CGRect` extension conform to your protocol:

```
extension CGRect: Interpolate {
    typealias T = CGRect
    static func interpolate(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> CGRect.T {
        var returnRect = CGRect()
        returnRect.origin.x     = from.origin.x + (to.origin.x-from.origin.x) * progress
        returnRect.origin.y     = from.origin.y + (to.origin.y-from.origin.y) * progress
        returnRect.size.width   = from.size.width + (to.size.width-from.size.width) * progress
        returnRect.size.height  = from.size.height + (to.size.height-from.size.height) * progress
        return returnRect
    }
}

var from = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1) // (0, 0, 1, 1)
var to = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 0, height: 0)   // (1, 1, 0, 0)

CGRect.interpolate(from, to: to, progress: 1)      // (1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Also, this would make `NSString` conform to protocol `Interpolate` easily, like:

```
extension NSString: Interpolate {
    typealias T = NSString
    static func interpolate(from: T, to: T, progress: CGFloat) -> NSString.T {
        //...
        return "" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note you could simplify this slightly by using `Self` in the protocol requirement (i.e `static func interpolate(from: Self, to: Self, progress: CGFloat) -> Self`) – and then ditching the redundant typealiases in the conforming types.